# Use orthogonal projection matrix to create centered version matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

1. We have an $m \times n$ matrix $A$. We want to get the orthogonal projections of the columns in $A$, onto any concrete vector $\overrightarrow{r}\in R_n$, creating the matrix $A_o$ with these.
2. Now by using the above we are supposed to for a 
   $m \times n$ matrix $A$, create the matrix $A_c$ (consisting of the centered version of the columns from $A$ (centered version of a column is equivalent to the difference between the values and the mean of all the values in the column)).

It is given that a vector $\overrightarrow{d}$ consisting of only $1$'s, if this vector is multiplied by the $m \times n$ matrix $A_m$ (containing the mean values of matrix $A$),
returns the orthogonal projection of matrix $A$ onto vector $\overrightarrow{d}$. Now this I guess does not imply that this fact withholds for *any* vector, so it might not even be relevant in our case.
Now the understanding behind this I don't really see.

Now the task is to use (1) in order to create what is required in (2). Now I can't really see the relation between (1) and (2). Any suggestions are highly appreciated.